# How to mount disk for user when a new user account is create on a linux cluster?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

Suppose there is a linux HPC cluster with 100 computer nodes whose users are managed by OpenLDAP. What I want to know is when I create a new user in LDAP, I can mount a specific storage for that user only under his home directory. The idea is equivilent to add a new entry in /etc/fstab when a user is created, but I believe it is not feasible to edit /etc/fstab to acheive this goal. I think an idea way is to have some service that can sync information from LDAP, and when a user is created it should be able to mount a disk according to some predefine rule or script.

Comment: udisks2 + polkit I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for auto-mounter with LDAP support.

See also: [OpenLDAP FAQ-O-MATIC -- How to use AutoFS with OpenLDAP?](https://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/599.html)